# how to retrieve mysql database information

Tags: php, mysql, database

i want the user to be able to view the reservation details after entering an email address

the code below shows all data in the database, what do i add to make only the user's reservation details show because

```
$username="root";$password="";
    $database="hotel";mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $query="SELECT * FROM reservation";$result=mysql_query($query);
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);mysql_close();
    echo "<b>
    <center>Database Output</center>
    </b>
    <br>
    <br>";
    $i=0;while ($i < $num) {$field1name=mysql_result($result,$i,"r_id");

    $field4name=mysql_result($result,$i,"r_rooms");
    $field5name=mysql_result($result,$i,"r_type");
    echo "<b>
    Room NO: $field1name 
    CheckIN date: $field2name</b>
    <br>
    Checkout date: $field3name<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change your query from:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM reservation";
```

to something like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE `email_column` = '$useremail'";
```

`email_column` : needs to be the column name where you store the emails

`$useremail` : is the user email you want to fetch the data for.

Comment: thanks, I've gotten creative and added a field which request for the email instead of having to go into the source code to enter the email